# SFML Network communication between two computers in different subnets

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, sfml

Ok so i wanted to create very simple test of UDP & TCP client and server communication.

```
void runTcpServer(unsigned short port)
{
    sf::TcpListener listener;

    if (listener.listen(port) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    std::cout << "Server is listening to port " << port << ", waiting for connections... " << std::endl;

    sf::TcpSocket socket;
    if (listener.accept(socket) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    std::cout << "Client connected: " << socket.getRemoteAddress() << std::endl;

    const char out[] = "JAZDA JAZDAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    if (socket.send(out, sizeof(out)) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    std::cout << "Message sent to the client: \"" << out << "\"" << std::endl;

    char in[128];
    std::size_t received;
    if (socket.receive(in, sizeof(in), received) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    std::cout << "Answer received from the client: \"" << in << "\"" << std::endl;
}

void runTcpClient(unsigned short port)
{
    sf::IpAddress server;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Type the address or name of the server to connect to: ";
        std::cin >> server;
    } while (server == sf::IpAddress::None);

    sf::TcpSocket socket;

    if (socket.connect(server, port) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    std::cout << "Connected to server " << server << std::endl;

    char in[128];
    std::size_t received;
    if (socket.receive(in, sizeof(in), received) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    std::cout << "Message received from the server: \"" << in << "\"" << std::endl;

    const char out[] = "JAZDAAAA JAZDAAA JECHANKA KANKA";
    if (socket.send(out, sizeof(out)) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    std::cout << "Message sent to the server: \"" << out << "\"" << std::endl;
}

void runUdpServer(unsigned short port)
{   // Create a socket to receive a message from anyone
    sf::UdpSocket socket;

    if (socket.bind(port) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    std::cout << socket.getLocalPort() << " connected with this port\n";
    std::cout << "Server is listening to port " << port << ", waiting for a message... " << std::endl;

    char in[128];
    sf::Packet packet_in, packet_out;
    sf::IpAddress sender;

    unsigned short senderPort;
    if (socket.receive(packet_in, sender, senderPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    packet_in >> in;
    std::cout << "Message received from client " << sender << ": \"" << in << "\"" << std::endl;

    const char out[] = "JAZDA JAZDAAAAAA";
    packet_out << out;
    if (socket.send(packet_out, sender, senderPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    std::cout << "Message sent to the client: \"" << out << "\"" << std::endl;
}

void runUdpClient(unsigned short port)
{
    sf::IpAddress server;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Type the address or name of the server to connect to: ";
        std::cin >> server;
    } while (server == sf::IpAddress::None);
    sf::Packet packet_out, packet_in;
    sf::UdpSocket socket;
    std::cout << socket.getLocalPort() << "connected with this port \n";

    const char out[] = "JECHANKA KANKA";
    packet_out << out;

    if (socket.send(packet_out, server, port) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;

    std::cout << "Message sent to the server: \"" << out << "\"" << std::endl;
    char in[128];
    std::size_t received;
    sf::IpAddress sender;
    unsigned short senderPort;

    if (socket.receive(packet_in, sender, senderPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;

    packet_in >> in;
    std::cout << "Message received from " << sender << ": \"" << in << "\"" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned short port = 50001;
    char protocol;
    std::cout << "Do you want to use TCP (t) or UDP (u)? ";
    std::cin >> protocol;
    char who;
    std::cout << "Do you want to be a server (s) or a client (c)? ";
    std::cin >> who;
    if (protocol == 't')
    {
        // Test the TCP protocol
        if (who == 's')
            runTcpServer(port);
        else
            runTcpClient(port);
    }
    else
    {
        // Test the unconnected UDP protocol
        if (who == 's')
            runUdpServer(port);
        else
            runUdpClient(port);
    }
}
```

I decided not to cut from the code almost anything cause i dont really know where exactly problem is lying.

The good thing is that its working in every way on localhost(when i type localhost as ip of server i wanna connect to), but when im trying to test it with my friend on other computer it doesnt work anyway. Just after typing adress of server client cant connect to server in TCP and in UDP client sends message, but server dont get it. We have unlocked ports in windows firewall, as well as tried to turn off firewall completely. We also using in any case external ip adress (80..), checked on https://www.whatismyip.com. I tried to do it on packets as well as raw data(as seen on example). In any case it works properly in local network but not in external network.

Comment: If the receiving side is behind a router it will most likely need proper port forwarding for incoming traffic. I'd bet that's the issue.

Comment: I'm a bit not understand, to be honest.

Comment: But genereally you think that problem lying in somewhere outside code? Or inside. I checked out how to do port forwarding but its kinda sophisticated with my internet provider due to changing IP and strange modem application. You know, but when you installing something which is using internet, it wroking without that work. How applications like games etc connecting with servers?

Comment: Ah, ignore my comment above regarding header files. Wrote that while still mostly sleeping and thought it's a different question; stupid mobile app. :(

Comment: Yes, it's most likely something with port forwarding, which typically has nothing to do with your ISP directly. There are dynamic DNS services (both free and paid) that allow you to register a sub domain, which will then point to your public internet IP, even when using dynamic IP addresses.

Comment: *"How applications like games etc connecting with servers?"* Those are using outbound connections, which won't require forwarding. But for incoming connections, your router has to know which local machine to forward packets to.